# Unable to understand why error "Compile error: Expected list separator or )" appear

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a VBA form to auto fill cells. Currently coding the SAVE button with the following code:

```
    Private Sub SBut_Click()
    'Copy input values to sheet.
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("QC")
    lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    With ws
        .Cells(1Row, 1).Value = Now
        .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    End With
        
    With ws
        .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = a.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = b.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = D.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Ctl.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = A1.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = B1.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 9).Value = AbS1.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 10).Value = AbS2.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 11).Value = AbS3.Value
    End With
        
    'Clear input controls.
    a.Value = ""
    b.Value = ""
    D.Value = ""
    Ctl.Value = ""
    A1.Value = ""
    B1.Value = ""
    AbS1.Value = ""
    AbS2.Value = ""
    AbS3.Value = ""
    'Close UserForm.
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

The aim of the code is to populate the cells mentioned above with the input from the form. However, I am facing a challenge with this piece of code:

```
With ws
        .Cells(1Row, 1).Value = Now
        .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    End With
```

Without this code, the form function as expected with no errors. However, when adding the code above, VBA highlights:

```
.Cells(1Row, 1).Value = Now
```

When writing this line, VBA specifically highlight "Row", with the error "Compile error: Expected list separator or )", and if I run the form, VBA highlights the line as a whole and give me the following error  "Compile error: syntax error"

The aim of this part is when the save button is clicked, for the first cell in the row to be populated with a date/time stamp without the user needing to do so.

Can you please help me understanding what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You have `1Row` (One-Row) instead of `lRow` (L-Row) - See how in your question, it turns red?

Comment: You are right, I hate these simple mistakes. On VBA the number one looks the same as small L. Thank you for your help

Comment: almost the same... look very carefully... but glad i could help.